# Compare two lists of unequal length and non-matching elements

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of unequal length and non-matching values as shown below:

```
list_1 = [1,7,9]
list_2 = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.8,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.19,0.009]
```

For each value in `list_1` I want to extract its matching value in `list_2`. The result should be like this:

```
result[1:0.1,7:0.13,9:0.19]
```

Currently I have this:

```
find_minimum = min(len(list_1),len(list_2))
for i in range(find_minimum):
    print(list_1[i],list_2[i])
```

And this is the result:

```
1:0.1
2:0.2
3:0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look up python [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which allow a key to value mapping. You should also know that python is zero indexed and so the first entry of `list_1` is `list_1[0]`.

With a dictionary you can write a solution like

```
result = dict() # a new dictionary, could also just write result = {}
for i in list_1:
    result[i] = list_2[i-1]
print(result)
```

will print

```
{1: 0.1, 7: 0.13, 9: 0.19}
```

You'll often see people use a dict comprehension for this which would look like

```
result = {i: list_2[i-1] for i in list_1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking up the `i`-th index in `list_2`, you want to look up the `list_1[i]`-th index.

```
for i in range(find_minimum):
    print(list_1[i], list_2[list_1[i]])
```

If that's confusing to read, save `list_1[i]` in a temporary variable to make it easier to understand:

```
for i in range(find_minimum):
    index = list_1[i]
    print(index, list_2[index])
```

Comment: when you run it gives this result, like it goes one index ahead, whats wrong?   1 0.2 
7 0.14
9 0.009 @John